# Errno 13 could not open port /dev/serial/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0: Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: serial-port, raspbian, pci-e

Trying to use a USB device attached to my raspberry pi running PI OS Lite 64-bit. When trying to

```
access /dev/serial/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0
```

it get the following error in my log:

```
Unable to open serial port: [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/serial/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/serial/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0
```

when i try to connect to the other device

```
/dev/serial/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-port0
```

I have no issues.

```
pi@SV06PI:~ $ ls /dev/serial/by-path/*
/dev/serial/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.2:1.0-port0
/dev/serial/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0
```

```
pi@SV06PI:~ $ usb-devices

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 1
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=06.01
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 6.1.21-v8+ xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:01:00.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2109 ProdID=3431 Rev=04.21
S:  Product=USB2.0 Hub
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  7 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=02(commc) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=16 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d50 ProdID=614e Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Klipper
S:  Product=stm32f405xx
S:  SerialNumber=520021000151313132353838
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=02 Prot=01 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1a86 ProdID=7523 Rev=02.64
S:  Product=USB Serial
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=98mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=ch341

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=03 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=18d1 ProdID=0001 Rev=03.10
S:  Manufacturer=Ingenic Semiconductor CO., LTD.
S:  Product=HD USB Camera
S:  SerialNumber=Ucamera001
C:  #Ifs= 5 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#=0x3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio
I:  If#=0x4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=06.01
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 6.1.21-v8+ xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:01:00.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

I tried to connect to a specific device through the serial port but it wont.

Comment: Instead of a simple `ls /dev/serial/by-path/*` that doesn't tell you anything new, use an option/switch (e.g. `-l` for long output) to obtain the ***salient information pertaining to the error*** such as the owner, group, and ***permissions***.